# Permission inheritance on subsite et subsubsite

Tags: permissions, sub-site

I have a pretty specific question for you.
The context is :

1. I have a root site collection website (level 0) named A with 3 groups Owners Members Visitors. The person named Toto is in the group Visitors so he can access the main page.
2. I have a sub site (level 1) named B and with permission inheritance broken but also the 3 groups. Toto is not any more in the Visitors groups. So he can't access this sub site.
3. I have a sub sub site (level 2) named C and with permission inheritance broken but also the 3 groups. Toto is in the Visitors groups. So he can normally access this sub sub site (i have tested out this with a native sharepoint teamsite). In MY case (a personalized theme and 2 new permissions levels) Toto can't access this sub sub site
4. I have a sub sub sub site (level 3) named D and with permission inheritance broken but also the 3 groups. Toto is in the Visitors groups. So he can access this sub sub sub site. and YES it works he can access it.

So my question is why Toto can't access sub sub site C however he has the permission and why Toto can access sub sub sub site D only beacuse he have a pseudo-access to site C.

Can someone help me out with this particular case?

Comment: When breaking inheritance, did you use the existing group or created new ones.  For example Site C Visitor, C Member C Owner?

Comment: Right I did not mensionned that. Sorry. I used the existing groupe because I create these existing groups between the moment of the creation and this page which ask if existing groups or new group to be used. My point is this si a new group i created for the specific sub site.

Comment: I think Toto needs "limited access" to site B. Won't be able to do anything in B but allows access to C. You might be able to reduce those 4 permissions in the Limited profile. You might be helped by [this](http://365csi.nl/toolkit/permissions.html?l=en) overview

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if permission inheritance is broken inside the site C. I mean if inheritance is broken between the pages library and the site object, Toto would not be able to access to pages.
What do you see if you check permissions for Toto in the site ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your testing case are not correct and you think in some case it's working because of the sequence of your test :)
When adding / removing Toto from the Visitors group, you're adding/removing him for all level because visitors group is a root group (defined at root level).

Actually, there is only one Visitor group , at root level. Permissions inheritance allow you to define different permissions (read, contribute, etc..) at different levels for a specific group. But the group remain the same !

my advice for your design will be probably end on 2 differents groups, one with Toto inside, one without :)